# Using WHERE and ORDER BY together in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My Question : Select all the data of all the employees except Clerks.order them by their last
name

My query :

```
select * from employees WHERE job_id NOT like '%CLERK' AND order by last_name
```

but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `AND`

```
select * from employees 
WHERE job_id NOT like '%CLERK' 
order by last_name
```

Based on comments, with *pseudo code*

```
select * from employees 
WHERE job_id != 'CLERKS'
AND DateAppointedFielName BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate 
order by last_name
```

Comment: how can i write this --> Select all the data of employees except the CLERKS and the employees appointed between January 93 to August 97